# Declarar matriz multidimensional en symfony php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Trabajo con *PHP* - *Symfony 4*, estoy implementando una api, tengo la necesidad de declarar una matriz multidimensional de tres array que están pobladas de datos desde la db.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $aulaDetalle = $em->getRepository(Aula::class)->getAulaDetail($aula);
    $distributivos = $aulaDetalle->getDistributivos();
    $matriculados = $aulaDetalle->getMatriculados();

    $listaCalificaciones[] = "";

    foreach ($matriculados as $valor){
        $listaCalificaciones = $valor->getCalificaciones();
    }

    $datos = [$distributivos, $matriculados, $listaCalificaciones];
    var_dump($datos);
```

Error en postman

> Error: Maximum response size reached

Respecto al error amplié máximo response en *Postman* a *100mb* pero *Postman* se cierra, con ese comportamiento del mensaje asumo que la variable esta trayendo datos.

¿Es correcto como estoy declarando la matriz multidimensional `datos`?

Comment: Depende, si cada una de esas 3 variables son arrays entonces puede ser que si, si en cambio solo tienen tal vez un string o un number entonces es un simple array

Comment: Pero podemos salir de dudas muy rápido si le haces un `var_dump();` a `$datos`

Comment: @BetaM como estoy trabajando en una api lo único que tengo para probar es Postman, se puede ver ahí lo que hace var_dump();, respondiendo a tu respuesta anterior si todas esas variables son colecciones de datos

Comment: @BetaM me sale el siguiente error Error: Maximum response size reached en postman me imagino que es por la cantidad de datos que trae la variable $datos.

Comment: Revisa esto: https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033875073-My-requests-take-longer-time-to-receive-response

Comment: @BetaM le aumente la capacidad de maximo response a 100 pero es demasiada data se cierra el postman pero eso me indica que si trae datos si no, no se comportaría así.

Comment: No tengo mas aportes de momento, pero entonces considero tu pregunta debería incluir lo que has tratado y el mensaje de error que estás obteniendo para que sea amplia

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer de $datos un array asociativo, de esta forma:

```html
$distributivos = array(....);
$matriculados = array(....);
$listaCalificaciones = array(....);

$datos['distributivos'] = $distributivos;
$datos['matriculados'] = $matriculados;
$datos['calificaciones'] = $listaCalificaciones;
```

Comment: Que gano con un array asociativo, que están asociadas los array y puedo hacer una consulta como si fuera una tabla?

Comment: Sí, puedes tratarlo com un array individual, al tratarlo como $datos['matriculados'].